# Should the FAQ for this Site Contain Extra Information to Help Guide New Users?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Since this site is not designed specifically for programmers, we're likely to get many new users who are not as computer or tech-savvy as the user-base we would typically see lurking in one of the trilogy sites.

As a result, a lot of basic, fundamental etiquette guidelines **may not** be well understood by users who are not just new to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair but who are also new to the Stack Exchange network itself.

Is any specific information we should add in the FAQ to further help guide these new users?

**UPDATE:** You should list items separately so they can be voted on independently.

Answer (score 2):

The FAQ should list this item:

- In general, driving questions are "off-topic".  However, since test drives are an important step in diagnosing problems, driving questions that apply to the diagnosis of a specific problem you are facing are on-topic.  Source:  [Are driving questions on-topic?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-driving-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Sure -- that's the primary role of the FAQ.

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq

Right now you don't have any pro-tem moderators:

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/about

Once you have pro-tem moderators appointed (soon!) they have edit rights on the /faq page, and we encourage them to customize the top part of it to *your* community.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was looking for more specifics to help speed up the process of actually determining *what* should go in the FAQ.  When we finally get members in place who are able to edit the FAQ, I'm hoping they can use any community info from this post to aid in making thorough updates to the FAQ.