# Why is key tracking a bad question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, asking-questions

I understand that this site is mainly dedicate to car care and maintenance, however my [question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1110/how-do-i-keep-track-of-my-car-keys) was closed as off-topic. Losing keys, I feel is a on topic problem but apparently the comment thinks other wise (three downvotes and a mod closure). My question here is how exactly is this off topic so that I don't make this mistake again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a question you would ask of a motor vehicle repair professional. They may *happen* to know the answer, but not because of their expertise in vehicle repair.

Your question would be better suited to a car *enthusiast* site, a site for the end user/consumer. We've [discussed](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-driving-questions-on-topic/4#4) whether *this* site would include driving and car "enthusiast" questions, but the community decided it was outside the scope of "Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair."

Answer (score 6):

I don't think losing your keys could in any way be construed as repairing your motor vehicle.

Comment: My confusion was, and this was my fault for not taking the time to research the meta, was that this was an all general car SE site and not limited to maintenance and repair. I see that now.

Answer (score 3):

I look at it like this: are you asking about something that's broken on your car?  Are you asking how to improve something about the car?  The good questions all seem to start with a problem that's directly related to a specific car and one that's currently giving you fits, prompting a turn to the internet.

For example: a great key-related question would be something like "I just broke the key off in my door and can't get a grip with pliers - can I disassemble the handle and, if so, how?"

*My short answer to that hypothetical question, by the way, is no, you're probably screwed.*