# How about renaming this site to "Motor Vehicle Maintenanance and Safe Driving"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was looking for a stackexchange site dealing with motor vehicles (both maintenance and safe driving). This is the closest as to what has been proposed.

From my point of view, it would be convenient to have a site to ask questions about safe driving (based on road conditions, weather etc.). Since this site is still in Beta stage, opening another site may be detrimental to both sites in increasing their popularity.

Therefore I suggest to rename this site to, "Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Safe Driving". As you can notice, I have removed the work repair as "Maintenance" somewhat covers issues related to repair as well.

I would appreciate discussion on this request.

Answer (score 7):

IMHO no, topics on driving are currently off topic as [this meta post discusses](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/85). Also maintenance and repair are not the same thing. This site is about both and is not limited to maintenance only items.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that by strict definition "Maintenance" and "Repair" are not the same, I suggested it to shorten the title and make room for "Safe Driving" or just "Driving". Mentioning this explicitly would help users to understand that the site is also about driving.

Comment: Looks like the site proposed for driving only got deleted. Therefore, if it was merged here, it would get an opportunity to survive.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz The fact that it can't make it out of Area 51 is not a reason to bring it here. We are trying to attract automotive repair professionals, and this (IMHO) would water the site down.